# Dataframe Lookup rows to return Index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lookup

I have a dataframe as per

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie Final
10     20    30       30
15     25    35       25
```

I like to create a new column with the header such that it will be:

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie Final NewColumn
10     20    30       30  Charlie
15     25    35       25  Bravo
```

I tried this but it did not give the correct results:

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Final)
```

**Edit:**

I tried both answers and it works but because I have many other columns, is there a way I can limit the lookup function to just Alpha Bravo and Charlie columns? (It is returning me other columns)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a 100% numpy vectorized solution using broadcasted comparison:

```
i = df.values
j = df.Final.values

df['NewColumn'] = df.columns[(i == j[:, None]).argmax(1)]
```

```
df

   Alpha  Bravo  Charlie  Final NewColumn
0     10     20       30     30   Charlie
1     15     25       35     25     Bravo
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [84]: df['NewColumn'] = df.drop('Final',1).eq(df['Final'], axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   Alpha  Bravo  Charlie  Final NewColumn
0     10     20       30     30   Charlie
1     15     25       35     25     Bravo
```